# extension method in gridview eval

Tags: asp.net

I have an extension method that I wrote but when I use it on an aspx page to render a label inside a gridview, it doesn't work.

```
<asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TheStatus").ToMyStatus() %>'></asp:Label>
```

The extension method is a file called Appfunctions.cs:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string ToMyStatus(byte TheStatus)
    {
        //mycode
    }
}
```

I've seen posts that say a namespace needs to be added with the Imports statement in the aspx page but the extention ToMyStatus is not in any particular namespace.

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have missed **this** and type conversion.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string ToMyStatus(this byte TheStatus)
    {
        return "Hello : " + TheStatus;
    }
}
```

**Markup**

```
<asp:Label ID="lblStatus" 
           runat="server" 
           Text='<%#  ((byte)Eval("TheStatus")).ToMyStatus() %>'>
</asp:Label>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot about adding the 'this' statement. Why do I need a cast? The variable "TheStatus" is already defined as a byte?

Comment: Return type of Eval() method is Object.